# Update parameter values as well as stack creation based on the selection of the environment type in Cloud Formation

Tags: configuration, aws-cloudformation, user-input, environment

Is it possible in Cloud Formation to pick an environment in a parameter field in the UI of Cloud Formation (e.g. Windows or Linux) and based on this choice update all following parameters as well as the stack that is being created? I need to choose between Windows and Linux machines during the creation of a new stack using a template and need to ensure that the correct stack is being created with different configuration based on the environment.

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly its **not fully possible** to do this.

You can't change number of parameters, or their properties (name, default value) based on whether you choose windows or linux on other parameter.

But using [conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) you **can decide which resources are created** in stack based on whether you set one parameter to windows or linux.

For example, you can have parameter and condition:

```
Parameters:

  MyOS:
    Type: String
    Default: Linux
    AllowedValues: [Windows, Linux]

Conditions:

  IsLinux: 
    !Equals [!Ref MyOs, 'Linux']
```

Then using the `IsLinux` condition you can manipulate which resources are created, which outputs are returned, and which resource attributes have linux, or windows, specific values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I feared that this would be the case ... yes I could use conditionals to specify which resources get created specifically, however, the stack creation depends on yet other parameters which only should be selectable by the user when either linux or windows is specified .... so I guess I will have to use two separate templates for each environment after all ...

Comment: @Benny Yes. CloudFormation is quite limited. You can also have a look at Service Catalog. There you can define two templates (called products), and your users just launch the ones they want. Each product would have its own specific settings.

Comment: Great thanks! I don't think that this is applicable, since we do not need to create complete services, more of some standard scripts to provision barebone Windows or Linux machines